# PyInstaller Error: AttributeError with pythoncom Module

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm encountering an error while attempting to create a .exe file for my Python app using PyInstaller. When running `pyinstaller --onefile -w my_script.py`, I consistently receive the following error:

`AttributeError: Failed to retrieve attribute __file__ from module pythoncom`

Here are the packages I've used in my script:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Label, messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import time
```

Despite researching online solutions for a couple of hours, I haven't found any that work. Appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue. Thanks!

Comment: try setting up your project in a virtual environment and trying again  Also post the full traceback not just the error message

Answer (score 0):

The error might be related to a compatibility issue with the pythoncom module used by pywin32 and PyInstaller.

Comment: This sounds like a comment / guess, not an answer. Please read [answer].